# Angular-route trouble

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I don't know how exactly show my problem.
I'm trying dynamically change content with address changing.
If I don't use `$locationProvider` the '#' appears in address and I don't need it.
So if I use `$locationProvider` the `<base>` is needed. But when I add `<base>` my project doesn't see all outer css and scripts.
[image]

Here's plunker if it can help to understand :) Only first two sub menu contains href
http://plnkr.co/edit/pggakYtKS9xgxeMuKPEC?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can disable requireBase property as below.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
      });
```

Comment: Now it show such error: Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/ng/areq?p0=logOutController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)

Comment: And address now show not whole path, it looks like: 'localhost:11111/view1'

Comment: Please add below line in app.config section. I think it should work now.

Comment: $routeProvider.otherwise("/view1"). Please add this line at the end of app.config section. It  should work now.

Comment: Done but address still cutted

Comment: If you need full address, you need to set base href in index.html and set requireBase bollean to true.